# How can I iterate through a MySQL result set?

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here is the code I'm using:

```
# Run the query against the database defined in .yml file.
# This is a Mysql::result object - http://www.tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/
@results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(@sql_query)
```

In my View, here's what I do to see the values:

```
<pre><%= debug @results %></pre>
Outputs: #<Mysql2::Result:0x007f31849a1fc0>

<% @results.each do |val| %>
   <%= val %>
<% end %>
Outputs: ["asdfasdf", 23, "qwefqwef"] ["sdfgdsf", 23, "asdfasdfasdf"]
```

So imagine I query something like `select * from Person`, and that returns a result set such as:

```
ID      Name      Age
1       Sergio    22
2       Lazlow    28
3       Zeus      47
```

How can I iterate through each value and output it?

The documentation here is not useful because I have tried methods that supposedly exist, but the interpreter gives me an error saying that those methods don't exist. Am I using the wrong documentation?

http://www.tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you are using mysql2 gem then you should be getting the mysql2 result object and according to the docs you should be able to do the following

```
results.each do |row|
  # conveniently, row is a hash
  # the keys are the fields, as you'd expect
  # the values are pre-built ruby primitives mapped from their corresponding field types in MySQL
  # Here's an otter: http://farm1.static.flickr.com/130/398077070_b8795d0ef3_b.jpg
end
```

Checkout the documentation [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.3.11/frames)

So in you case you can do the following

```
<% @results.each do |val| %>
   <%= "#{val['id']}, #{val['name']}, #{val['age']}" %>
<% end %>
```

**Edit**: you seem to be referring to the wrong doc check the Mysql2 gems doc.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I can't believe I was reading the wrong docs. :)

Answer (score 16):

You could try using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query` instead of `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` which returns a [`ActiveRecord::Result`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html) (available in rails 3.1+)

Then you can access it in various ways like `.rows`, `.each`, or `.to_hash`

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html):

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('SELECT id, title, body FROM posts')
result # => #<ActiveRecord::Result:0xdeadbeef>


# Get the column names of the result:
result.columns
# => ["id", "title", "body"]

# Get the record values of the result:
result.rows
# => [[1, "title_1", "body_1"],
      [2, "title_2", "body_2"],
      ...
     ]

# Get an array of hashes representing the result (column => value):
result.to_hash
# => [{"id" => 1, "title" => "title_1", "body" => "body_1"},
      {"id" => 2, "title" => "title_2", "body" => "body_2"},
      ...
     ]

# ActiveRecord::Result also includes Enumerable.
result.each do |row|
  puts row['title'] + " " + row['body']
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `:as => :hash`:

```
raw = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
raw.each(:as => :hash) do |row|
  puts row.inspect # row is hash
end
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using `(:as => :hash)` and not just `.each`?

Comment: @Termato In my laptop (Windows 7), Rails 3, it does not output `row` as hash, thus I explicitly add `(:as => :hash)`. Totally agree just use `.each` if it works:)

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Look for @results.fields for column header.

Example: @results = [[1, "Sergio", 22],[2, "Lazlow", 28],[3, "Zeus", 47]]

```
@results.fields do |f|
  puts "#{f}\t"  # Column names
end

puts "\n"

@results.each do |rows| # Iterate through each row
  rows.each do |col| # Iterate through each column of the row
    puts "#{col}\t"
  end
  puts "\n"
end
```

Hope it is helpful.