# Rails 3 execute custom sql query without a model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I need to write a standalone ruby script that is supposed to deal with database. I used code given below in rails 3

```
@connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
:adapter => "mysql2",
:host => "localhost",
:database => "siteconfig_development",
:username => "root",
:password => "root123"
)

results = @connection.execute("select * from users")
results.each do |row|
puts row[0]
end
```

but getting error:-

```
`<main>': undefined method `execute' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x00000002867548> (NoMethodError)
```

what i am missing here?

**SOLUTION**

After getting solution from denis-bu i used it following way and that worked too.

```
@connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
            :adapter => "mysql2",
            :host => "localhost",
            :database => "siteconfig_development",
            :username => "root",
            :password => "root123"
)

sql = "SELECT * from users"
@result = @connection.connection.execute(sql);
@result.each(:as => :hash) do |row| 
   puts row["email"] 
end
```

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(...)
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(...)
```

Comment: FWIW, Using empty params is not idiomatic ruby. So do `connection.execute` rather than `connection().execute`

Comment: Works on Rails 4 also.

Comment: https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/execute_sql less code is needed plus you can do it in directly rails console

Answer (score 100):

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
connection.execute("SQL query")
```

Comment: In this case, connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection;  connection.execute("SQL query") would work.  Less typing!

Comment: Or just `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SQL query")`

Comment: This connection may have to be returned to the connection pool afterwards to avoid threading issues: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.checkin(connection)` http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool

Answer (score 39):

I'd recommend using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query` instead of `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` which returns a [`ActiveRecord::Result`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html) (available in rails 3.1+) which is a bit easier to work with.

Then you can access it in various the result in various ways like `.rows`, `.each`, or `.to_hash`

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html):

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('SELECT id, title, body FROM posts')
result # => #<ActiveRecord::Result:0xdeadbeef>


# Get the column names of the result:
result.columns
# => ["id", "title", "body"]

# Get the record values of the result:
result.rows
# => [[1, "title_1", "body_1"],
      [2, "title_2", "body_2"],
      ...
     ]

# Get an array of hashes representing the result (column => value):
result.to_hash
# => [{"id" => 1, "title" => "title_1", "body" => "body_1"},
      {"id" => 2, "title" => "title_2", "body" => "body_2"},
      ...
     ]

# ActiveRecord::Result also includes Enumerable.
result.each do |row|
  puts row['title'] + " " + row['body']
end
```

note: copied my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37403273/341692)

Comment: As stated, exec_query returns the actual results - what I want, while execute just returns status information.

Comment: As of Rails-7.0 and Ruby-3.1, `.to_hash` is undefined ([Ver.7.0.4 doc](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html)). Instead, `.to_a` returns an Array of Hash. Make sure the column names are unique in using `.to_a`, e.g., specify `"SELECT 3 a,4 b,5 c;"` as opposed to `"SELECT 3,4,5;"`.

Answer (score 25):

You could also use [find_by_sql](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Querying/find_by_sql)

```
# A simple SQL query spanning multiple tables
Post.find_by_sql "SELECT p.title, c.author FROM posts p, comments c WHERE p.id = c.post_id"
> [#<Post:0x36bff9c @attributes={"title"=>"Ruby Meetup", "first_name"=>"Quentin"}>, ...]
```

Comment: my script is outside rails application so i don't think find_by_sql would work.

Comment: you're right, i read your question too quickly. This answer might help others who come to this page based on your question title.

Comment: how to get not an array but relation?

Answer (score 4):

How about this :

```
@client = TinyTds::Client.new(
      :adapter => 'mysql2',
      :host => 'host',
      :database => 'siteconfig_development',
      :username => 'username',
      :password => 'password'

sql = "SELECT * FROM users"

result = @client.execute(sql)

results.each do |row|
puts row[0]
end
```

You need to have TinyTds gem installed, since you didn't specify it in your question I didn't use Active Record

Comment: Sure, TinyTds is whole other gem.. It is not ActiveRecord. To use it you should install it separately.

Comment: I don't want to use any additional GEM as long as mysql2 and active-record is available

Comment: Good, you should mention that in your question (tag/title)

Comment: TinyTDS works with MSSQL and Sybase, it doesn't work with MySQL. ant: *You* should mention that in your answer, and not assume that the OP is using the same niche DBMS as you are.