# SQL/Rails return count of unique values from a group of records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following SQL query which extracts the number of unique websites from a table, the count of the number of records for each of the websites and the number of unique users that visited each website.

```
"SELECT title, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id), COUNT(title) FROM weblogs GROUP BY title"
```

The table is arranged as follows:

```
weblog_id | title | user_id
---------------------------
1         | BBC   | 1
2         | BBC   | 1
3         | BBC   | 2
4         | Sky   | 1
5         | Sky   | 1
```

The above query will return:

```
title    | COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)   | COUNT(title)
---------------------------------------------------
BBC      | 2                         | 3
Sky      | 1                         | 2
```

Whilst this works in its current form by executing the SQL string in Rails using exec_query, I have struggled to replicate the same results using Rails' query methods (I'm not a Rails dev but am having to work in Rails). Any ideas on how to build this query up using Rails methods?

**EDIT**

I can extract the individual total website hit counts and unique users per website using two separate queries. The following gives the count of each website

```
weblogs.all.group(title).count
```

And the following gives the count of unique users for each website:

```
weblogs.all.group(title).distinct.count(user_id)
```

Is there a way of combining these into one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will work:

```
weblogs.all.group(title).select("COUNT(DISTINCT user_id), COUNT(title), title")
```

You also can execute your custom sql query
[Rails 3 execute custom sql query without a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408285/rails-3-execute-custom-sql-query-without-a-model)

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for. I guess I expected it to look a bit more Railsy and a bit less SQL like.