# i want to execute an sql query in ruby to use the result to make some tests in my views

Tags: sql, ruby

this is the query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM public.member_roles , public.members , public.users
    WHERE public.users.id = public.members.user_id AND public.members.id = public.member_roles.member_id AND public.member_roles.role_id = 4 ;
```

in my views if this query return 1 , a text area is ganna be disabled

Comment: Do you mean in Ruby? or Do you mean in Rails?
Moreover, how is your database schema wrt users, members and member_roles?

Comment: yes i mean in ruby in my controller , i wanna generate an instance variable  , and use it in the view , i'm sorry if my question is a little stupid but i'm a newbie in ruby on rails and i'm really stuck

Comment: question is fine I think why it put on hold? many time we fetch such situation. I was in big trouble for the same situation and I posted answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in rails

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(your_sql_here)
```

you can find more info on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408285/rails-3-execute-custom-sql-query-without-a-model) question. Hope this help you.

this will return Mysql2::Result object (if you are using mysql db and mysql2 gem. I belive for PG also it give similar object. to fetch data from it. here is a [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.2.6/Mysql2/Result) for Mysql2::Result.

Comment: @manag = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.member_roles , public.members , public.users
WHERE public.users.id = public.members.user_id AND public.members.id = public.member_roles.member_id AND public.member_roles.role_id = 4)")

Comment: this actually worked for me but i steal don't know how to use @manag value

Comment: use manage.first.first it will give you count. to look how this object is what it exactly have you need to log @manage.to_json

Comment: thanks a lot bro , i'm really stuck with ruby , i'm passing my final year project with ruby i thought that it's easy but here i am , here is my skype : achref_rezgui add me i'm sure i'm ganna need ur experience