# Write MySQL2 result to an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, mysql2

I want to convert this:

```
courses = client.query("SELECT LCASE(name) FROM courses")
```

into an array, so I can easily loop through elements in some existing code, much appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the docs? http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.2.6/file/README.rdoc

Comment: yeah I have read through the relevant areas of what you have linked me. I feel really stupid asking such a basic question, but I think I just need to see a working example to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Ok..I see. Look at the answers here for some more concrete examples:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836805/how-can-i-iterate-through-a-mysql-result-set . Maybe those help a little bit to get started.

Answer (score 1):

If that `courses` object is a `Mysql2::Result` you already can because it includes the `Enumerable` module. So you can use `each`, `select`, `first` and all the others methods from the module. Anyway, if you actually want an array object

```
courses = client.query("SELECT LCASE(name) FROM courses").to_a
```

`to_a` is from `Enumerable` module as well

```
courses = client.query("SELECT LCASE(name) AS name FROM courses")
course_names = courses.map { |course| course['name'] }
course_names.each { |course_name| puts course_name }
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work still, it says something about hash converting to a string, I will show you how I am using it to see if you can spot the errors of my ways, thanks in advance you are a life saver!

https://gyazo.com/bd696eb4cad4262d4849c2be872c7908

Comment: I saw the code but what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Basically I want the variable "courses", to be an array that contains a bunch of strings from one of the columns in my database. Thanks again.

Comment: I updated my answer. Try those three lines to see if you can print the course names

Comment: yeah that worked perfectly (it prints off the course names), is "course_names" now a string array containing the variables?

Comment: It's an array of strings from your database, table courses, field name, with LCASE function applied.

Comment: So where you have "puts course_name"

could I do this to write the course names to an array:

course_names.each { course_names_array = |course_name| }

Comment: Its values are just strings