# How To Read Database Result in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am sending raw SQL to a MySQL table in a RoR action:

```
sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM testtabl WHERE gender= 'female' AND 
ROUND(height, 2) = ROUND('#{height}' , 2);"

sql_result1 = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql1)

logger.debug('count is: '+sql_result1.to_s)
```

How can I access value 'cnt' from sql_result1?

Log shows:

```
count is: #<Mysql2::Result:0xb73c6c0>
```

Comment: why do you need to use raw sql if you are already using activerecord ?

Comment: Edit your post and add the output of `p sql_result1`.

Comment: Try `sql_result1.to_h` to maybe get a Hash...

Comment: @Subash: Because I want to use the ROUND() function.

Comment: You could use `Model.where(gender: 'female').where('round(height, 2) = round(?, 2)', height).count`, no?

Comment: @mu is too short : how do I replace the variable if it is coming into the method as an argument.  I tried using #{height}, but it throws a syntax error.

Comment: `#{height}` only works in double quoted strings (and their ilk): `""`. You may have had single quoted strings. `'#{height}'` would go thru to MySQL as a string literal and get bounced.

Comment: It's `sql_result1.to_a[0]`. Courtesy of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836805/how-can-i-iterate-through-a-mysql-result-set

Comment: @Phlip Thanks, that worked.

Comment: @muistooshort: This worked.  can you please add this as an answer so I can mark it as resolved and give you the points?

Comment: I tried to add my comment as an answer and StackOverflow converted it to a comment because it was too short. I thought we were trying to be "more welcoming" here...

Comment: Oh, also, you are comparing floats for exact equality in there. `round(.., 2)` does _not_ mean "magically create a number that always matches a similar number". Floating point precision can still create numbers that should be the same, but which fail equality tests.

Comment: @Phlip Combine your comment and mine and you should have enough of an answer. I don't care that much about points, I just want to help people and learn things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the OP's question is that a MySQL::Result behaves like an Enumeration, so you can convert it to an array of rows, then index the value of the first row:

`sql_result1.to_a[0][0]`

The answer to the OP's problem, however, is to simply let ActiveRecord do its thing:

`Model.where(gender: 'female').where('ROUND(height, 2) = ROUND(?, 2)', height).count`

The new problem is this compares floats for equality - `ROUND(.., 2)` notwithstanding. The fix is to compare a small range:

`Model.where(gender: 'female').where('ROUND(?, 2) BETWEEN ROUND(height, 2) - 0.0000001 AND ROUND(height, 2) + 0.0000001', height).count`

A less redundant database method to compare floats by range might be available...

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to use raw sql and get results into hash to be accessible. Try the below code where MODEL is the class name of the model. Like class name for users table could be User.

```
Model.connection.select_all(sql).to_hash
```

However, you could have used ActiveRecord where clause with inbuilt round method.